# Voltage Mode Control

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, flyback, switching-regulator, buck-boost

Since i started my training about design of DCDC I'm really confuse with control part.

At school i learned that DutyDycle=Vout/Vin for Buck,  and that's it.

But now, i see that, Duty cycle  is set by the output of error Amplifier and can indeed change from 0 to 100 according the output Voltage state. Is not at all a constant :/.

My second confusion and is my main question is about the picture joined.

If the result of EA is 0V (Line i drawn in red)[image]. What happen? duty cycle will be zero? This is not a problem ? because we should also have  DutyDycle=Vout/Vin.
Is there any constant  define for the PWM modul for exemple if EA is 0V -> give a fixe dutycycle ?

I'm so sorry my question is not totally clear because is not clear in my mind too.
If someone could give me a clear view about this part it will be a big party for me.

Answer (score 1):

The formula describing the relationship linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$ shows that the duty ratio \$D\$ controls the output voltage for a converter operated in continuous conduction mode or CCM: \$V_{out}=DV_{in}\$. That means that based on the input conditions, the control loop will permanently adjust the duty ratio to maintain \$V_{out}\$ on target. For instance, assume you want to deliver 5 V from a 10 V source, then the duty ratio will be 50% and the loop will maintain this value. The input source increases to 12 V, then the loop will reduce the duty ratio to 5/12 = 42% or so.

For a buck converter, the loop can freely adjust the duty ratio between 0 and 100%. 100% means the switch is permanently turned on. For instance, the source drops to 4.9 V then the loop will push the duty ratio to the maximum value, maintaining the switch on in an attempt to meet the 5-V target. Now if for some reason the load current drops to a very small value or disappears (unloaded converter), the converter enters the discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) and the relationship linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$ is no longer \$D\$ alone but involves the switching frequency and other variables. To maintain \$V_{out}\$ on target, the only option the loop has is to reduce the duty ratio down to a small value and eventually 0%: the converter skips cycles. This is a very common type of regulation. The below picture shows how the duty ratio is elaborated in voltage-mode control:

[image]

Please note that if many converters can accept 0% operation, most need an upper limit for the duty ratio as a main power switch in a boost converter or a buck-boost converter cannot stay on too long otherwise saturation of the magnetic element eventually occurs and the switch may be destroyed.

As a final note, whether a converter is operated in voltage- or current-mode control, it is still the duty ratio which sets the operating point. However, in voltage mode, the loop *directly* drives the duty ratio via the pulse width modulator (PWM) while in current mode, it *indirectly* sets it by setting the inductor peak current. You will find many details about the buck converter in a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) I gave at APEC in 2019.

Comment: thank you verry much @verbal Kint for your explanation, i will check the seminar , because i want to understand this since while .

 Tell me if i'm wrong. Let reduce the subject to CCM and voltage-mode control,

Vout=D.C*Vin it's a general relation between the Input Voltage and the output Voltage as you said "shows that the duty ratio D controls the output voltage ".
 But in real life we never have or mesured it  since the dutycycle is set by the loop?

Comment: Here you said 
"For instance, assume you want to deliver 5 V from a 10 V source, then the duty ratio will be 50% and the loop will maintain this value. The input source increases to 12 V, then the loop will reduce the duty ratio to 5/12 = 42% or so."

Can i suppose that , the Pin Vref(V+)  of the EA is the desired output and the Vout mesured( V-)  is input Voltage . Hence when the Vout mesured( V-)  change , the dutycycle adjust in order to have the good Vref.

Comment: if all my previous exemple are ok ,( and to be honest i hope. It make more sence for me), 
Will i really mesure 0% of duty cycle when Vref(V+) equal to    Vout mesured( V-)  ?

Comment: or we define a standard Dutycycle, accorrding Vout=D.C*Vin  and we define a small signal d.c with what i said before .

Comment: "that means that based on the input conditions, the control loop will permanently adjust the duty ratio to maintain Vout on target. " But the EA  do not see the input condition is connected only to vout and Vref.

Comment: Think of the buck as an open-loop converter, where the loop is not connected and you impose a certain duty ratio, 50% for instance. Then, in CCM, you have \$V_{out}=DV_{in}\$. If you change the input, the change will propagate to the output. Now, if you close the loop, the loop will react and correct the duty ratio via the PWM block. The 0% or 100% duty ratios are extremes respectively obtained when the error amp is at minimum output or a maximum output, beyond the ramp peak value. When V(-)=V(+), regulation is met and the duty ratio set to a value ensuring \$V_{out}\$ is on target.

Comment: Also, you have to realize that \$V_{out}=DV_{in}\$ is a theoretical formula and this expression is usually affected by coefficients reflecting ohmic losses (\$r_{DS(on)}\$, \$r_L\$), voltage drops (\$V_f\$), all *weighted* according to their occurrence in a switching cycle. Hence the need for a loop compensating for all these losses in normal operation.

Comment: Thank you ,I know about all this ,  my problem is really more about what happen around EA,only that . when V(-)=V(+) we have output of the amplifier should be 0V . But as to produce the PWM signal we compardd with SAWTOOTH. The result of this comparaison will give d.c=100%  and that make no sense , because when   V(-)=V(+)  we  should have Vout=D.C*Vout . You see where is my problem. I undurstand all thing that you are saying . but as soon as i do not have explanation about this specific point i will be lost and turning around.

Answer (score 0):

Only in an ideal buck circuit will \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}={\rm d.c.}\$. In a real circuit there will be resistive loss in the switch and inductor, and other factors that reduce the output voltage slightly compared to the ideal value. Or (as pointed out in comments) if the load draws very little current, repeated on cycles could push the output voltage above the ideal value.

Your circuit uses feedback to adjust the duty cycle as needed to achieve the desired output voltage.

> duty cycle will be zero?

Suppose the d.c. goes to zero. Then the feedback voltage (\$V_{FB}\$ in your diagram) will go to zero. Then the v-error amp output will increase, leading to an increase in d.c., so it won't stay at zero.

As long as the feedback voltage is below the target value, the error amp will keep increasing the d.c. until the target is reached (up to the maximum d.c. the circuit is capable of), and vice versa.

Comment: What is EA supposed to be? Is the OP asking about when the output voltage is zero? Or when the error amplifier output is zero?

Comment: The EA is the error amplifier.  I'm asking when the output of the Op is zéro, because we have vout =Vref.

So that mean i can forget Vout/Vin=d.c in real life we never have this ?

Comment: @kem, it's an approximation. Say you want Vout/Vin = 0.65. Then a d.c. of 0.65 is a close guess to what it should be. Maybe it will actually be 0.67. Maybe it will actually be 0.62. It won't very likely be 0.33 or 0.98 unless something else is very wrong with your circuit. From this approximation you can make reasonable design choices about your circuit, like the required inductor and capacitor values, estimate current and voltage ripple, etc.

Comment: ThePhoton thank you for you explanation, But i already know this , since i have basis and there is lot of general explanation on google. But My problem is about specific thing in regulation loop that i  do not find a clear explanation on the internet.

I fill like the Input voltage do not play a big role there and only the output voltage variation  and  Vref of EA  set the dutycycle , i'm right ? .@DKNguyen and  ThePhoton

Comment: @kem, you'll put attenuation (a voltage divider) in the feedback path, so that the Vfb is equal to Vref when Vout is at the target voltage. But the input voltage is very important because it determines how quickly the inductor charges when the switch is closed.

Comment: But the EA do not see the input condition is connected only to vout and Vref. So duty cycle is determined only thank to output , this is my problem

Comment: @kem, Vout is a function of Vin and d.c. (and Iout). Then d.c. is a function of Vout (probably filtered). So there is a closed loop. But Vin definitely contributes to the eventual d.c. once the loop gets into control.

Comment: @kem Correct me if I am wrong, but what you are saying is you do not see the control loop measuring Vin so you wonder why the equation contains Vin? In reality, we know that Vin controls the current ramp in the inductor, so Vin might not need to be directly measured (in certain control schemes anyways. There's a lot of nitty gritty stuff inside the control loop). I've not gone too deep into SMPS control loops myself I just know there are a lot of gotchas and variations.

Comment: @DKNguyen Let's take a example, i really want to understand.  In this tutorial  [link](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) Page 6. 
I can clearly see that , Dutycycle(D.C ) is set thank to feedback  Vref and Vout.  Hence the dutycycle in practice is not 
Vout=d.c*Vin
But  Vref(V+ of EA)=d.c*Vout ( V- of EA) . is it correct ? 
And what is the output of the EA if Vref=Vout ? zero ? , is there no a defined constant in this case to have Vout=d.c*Vout 

And what is the difference between D.C and d.c I'm so confuse ?

Comment: @kem The output of the error amplifier should be zero if Vref = Vout because that means no corrections are needed. Also, I think you might be mistaking steady-state relationships for transient ones in your discussion of the dependency of Vout on the duty cycle or Vref and the error amplifier. I believe load current also comes into play here since if there was zero load current, the output capacitor would eventually just charge up to Vin at any non-zero duty cycle. I am not sure what the assumptions for load current are though in the simple Vout = D*Vin equation.

Comment: @DKNguyen then when the output of EA is 0 dutycycle is 0V too since is compared with SAWTOOTH and we do not have Vout=D.C*Vout .That make no sense. ", I think you might be mistaking steady-state relationships for transient ones" , this is why i'm here and i'm asking for explanation :). Because i see the same anwser and explanation everywhere about what everybody already knows . But no one explain clearly about my question :) .