# Dutycycle DCDC control

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost, duty-cycle, control-loop

I will start with that, i already ask for this question in other topic but i didn't have any anwser about my question [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503525/voltage-mode-control/503536?noredirect=1#comment1286228_503536). 
Please don't go too far in explaning difficult thing not realated with my question , please first understang my question and my difficulty before to anwser.

Since months i'm totally lost in understanding regulation loop. I mean for exemple in DCDC buck i know that Duty cycle should be +/- Vout/Vin.

But i see that, Duty cycle is set by the output of error Amplifier and can indeed change from 0 to 100 according the output Voltage state. That mean when the output voltage is equal to the reference, the duty cycle is 0. So that mean the duty cycle should oscilate between this value, And when you see the circuit of control loop is totally normal.

But why why why , when we mesure the duty cycle i can't observe it,I see any variation of dutycycle, it's jusf fixe.  see the picture with dutycyle musured in a study state  and that is totally normal too since we should have D.V =Vout/Vin

[image]

What i observe is  Duty cycle of +/- Vout/Vin.

is there a trick somewhere.

Could someone take time to explain me in clear

Comment: Can you show your circuit schematic, where you are measuring and what your load is?

Comment: Vary the load on the output of the DC-DC converter while observing the PWM duty-cycle. You will see the duty-cycle change as load is varied. Now put a fixed load on the output of the DC-DC converter and vary the input voltage. You will see the duty-cycle change as the input voltage varies.

Comment: @Transistor I mesure at the gate of the Mostfet. that is directly the Dutycycle. But i mean this is not really important here about what load is. Because what i want to know is why i don't have something like here Page 20  [link]  (https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf)  , The dutycycle is changing permanently in order to have VOut=Vref and  we should have dutycycle equal to 0 when vout=Vref

Comment: @DwayneReid I know if i do that the dutycycle will change for sure. But what i want is to converge in one thing the link between what i see everywhere:" when you have a loop and  your input is  equal to your output, your dutycycle is 0% and varying around. But is not what i observe. I don't even see small variation. all i see is D.C=Vout/Vin

Comment: Maybe this circuit it's only use to produce PWM in transient and not in steady state ?  I'm totaly lost

Comment: If the input voltage remains constant and the load does not change, the duty cycle should not vary. There are exceptions to this - but those circuits either have special requirements or are deliberately varying the duty-cycle to achieve a more optimum operation. MPPT power supplies come to mind.

Comment: I may be missing what you are asking. There will usually be a bit of jitter in the PWM when the DC-DC converter is at steady-state. You would have to zoom your scope on one pulse to observe this. The amount of jitter in a well-designed converter will be quite small and may be hard to see.

Comment: @DwayneReid I'm totally agree with what you say. If vin remains  constant if load do not change , the dutycycle do not change.  But in this case, why do  we have something like in page 20 [link] (https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) saying when vref=Vout    D.C=0 %. Do you see what i mean ?

Comment: @DwayneReid i've just saw that i article

 "during steadystate regulation, the error-amplifier output will not go
below the voltage required to maintain the feedback voltage equal to VREF. So the output voltage will be" 

That mean even if Vout=Vref the output of the EA is not necessaty zero , but a value that allow to have +/- D.C=Vout/Vin right ?